# Ajax TabContainer "No Source Available" Error Message

Tags: asp.net, ajax, vb.net

I am working on a webpage with an Ajax TabContainer and attempting to display the results of a DB2 database query. I received the following error message and am not sure what this means or how to troubleshoot it. I have Ajax successfully installed in Visual Studio, where I am debugging from. The page has loaded to the point I can input data, so I can also see the tab container is working properly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
No Source Available
The source code cannot be displayed.
```

Call stack location:

```
AjaxControlToolkit.DLL!AjaxToolkit.ScriptControlBase.OnPreRender(System.EventArgs e) Line 271

Locating source for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs'. Checksum: MD5 {96 b3 2 f1 ca 17 5a 39 6e 7 1f c6 68 2f e2 bf}
The file 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'c:\Users\Stephen\Documents\Repos\Superexpert\AjaxControlToolkit\Server\AjaxControlToolkit\ExtenderBase\ScriptControlBase.cs'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what caused this to happen, but I was forced to re-install the Ajax Control ToolKit. This solved the problem.